# communication between two fragments . I am not using any already defined view for any of the fragments. I am just adding fragments at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, transactions, fragment

I have two fragments  MyFragment and MyFragment2 , an interface defined within MyFragment2.

**code for *MyFragment2*:**

```
public class MyFragment2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
public interface MyInterface2
{
    public void respond(String s);
}
EditText editText;
Button sendData;
MyInterface2 comm;
View v=getView();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_2,container,false);
    return v;
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.comm = (MyInterface2)getActivity();
    editText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text);
    sendData =(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sendData);
    sendData.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    try {
        String s = editText.getText().toString();
        comm.respond(s);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error:"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
 }
```

I am trying to send the content of editText from MyFragment2 to the fragment MyFragment by pressing the button ([Myfragment2 initially set on the main activity's view using the Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62TAg.png))

**The main activity's code is as follows*(my_layout is the id of layout in which  I am putting the fragments)*:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     MyFragment2.MyInterface2 {

    //String data;
   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MyFragment2 fragment2= new MyFragment2();
    FragmentManager fManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction= fManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.my_layout,fragment2,"MyFragment2");
    transaction.commit();

}

public void respond(String s)
{

   MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentManager fManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.my_layout,fragment);

    transaction.commit();
    fragment.getData(s);
  }
}
```

when I click the sendData button in fragment MyFragment2 , MyFragment2 gets replaced with fragment  Myfragment but no data change occurs in the MyFragmnet's textView and an error is also shown which I have catched in a try catch block from fragment MyFragment2([here is the image for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idQ6G.png)).
  **code for *MyFragment :***

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

TextView textView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,container,false);
    //textView =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.getText);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    textView =(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.getText);
 }

 public void getData(String data)
  {
    textView.setText(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily pass data between fragments using a callback or passing the arguments via a bundle.
Check out this article:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Zebesta thank you brother! (for visitors->)To retrieve data from the other side  I did this :  in onCreateView() method I did • Bundle b=getArguments();  • String s = b.getString("key");  • textView.setText(s);  And I got my work done!!

Answer (score 0):

onActivityCreated is no need. Uncomment ur text view initiation statement in onCreateView block.
Ensure you have text view in your respective layout file with same id you have passed